# How Do I Read In a Multipart Body into Dotnet API

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular

I am trying to read in a json object from my Angular front end, but if I try to use the `[FromBody]` tag, I receive an unsupported media type error. Without the tag, everything is null in the object parameter. The request I am sending to the api has both a file and json body in it.

Here is javascript request:

```
updateInventory(id: number, item: Inventory, file) {
    const reqBody: FormData = new FormData();
    if (file != null) {
      reqBody.append('file', file);
    }
    reqBody.append('json', new Blob([JSON.stringify(item)], {type: 'application/json'}));
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'inventory/' + id, reqBody);
  }
```

And here is the function receiving the data:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateInventory(int id, InventoryForUpdateDto inventoryForUpdate)
        {
            var inventoryFromRepo = await _repo.GetInventoryById(id);

            var imageFile = Request.Form.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Form.Files[0] : null;

            _map.Map(inventoryForUpdate, inventoryFromRepo);
            //Process data and file
            return Ok();
        }
```

I have checked how it comes across in Fiddler and the json body looks like this

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryApoSc8VsMbIB3GPg
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"vendorId":1,"storageId":13,"name":"name","description":"description","status":"active","cost":5,"reservedQty":0,"quantity":1625}
------WebKitFormBoundaryApoSc8VsMbIB3GPg--
```